# Dock window/panel for asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, dockpanel

Can anyone suggest a third party vendor, or how I could achieve implementing a Dock window into a web form in asp.net. Similar to the Visual Studio IDE, being able to dock to the side and the option to pin and unpin. I have tried Telerik but their Dock panels only dock horizontally and not to the side.

Any Suggestions, or links would helpful. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use some jquery / javascript to dock a standard ASP panel or a div. One example of docking using jquery: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/06/01/advanced-docking-using-jquery.aspx

Comment: +1..i have also need same thing if u got that then please tell me where from u found that @user1475479

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you cant dock horizontally with Telerik, the demo page here [Telerik Dock / Zone Orientation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dock/examples/zoneorientation/defaultcs.aspx) seems to suggest this is possible?

Comment: You can dock Horizontal but appears not vertical. The demo's also only indicate Horizontal docking.